# Square ABCD is given. A circle with radius AB and center A is drawn. this circle intersects the perpendicular bisector of BC in two points. Find ∠DOC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> A square $ABCD$ is given. A circe with radius $AB$ and center $A$ is drawn. This circle intersects the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ at two points, of which $O$ is closest to $C$. Find value of $\angle DOC$ in degrees.

*My method.* Took point $A$ as origin and square length $=1$. Then equation of circle is $x^2+y^2=1$. Next, I found out the coordinates of point $ABCD$. Now I took $y=-\frac{1}{2}$ as perpendicular bisector.Then, I get coordinates of point $B$. Next I calculated the angle and I got $105^\circ$ but answer is given as $75^\circ$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Described method gives right answer. Check your solution. Let $A(0,0)$, $B(1,0)$, $C(1,-1)$, $D(0,-1)$, $y=-\frac12$ is perpendicular bisector of $BC$. Then intersection of $x^2+y^2=1$ and $y=-\frac12$ is $x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $y=-\frac12$. Then $O(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2};-\frac12)$. In order to find $\angle DOC$ one can use scalar product. $\cos DOC=\frac{\vec{OD}\cdot\vec{OC}}{OD\cdot OC}=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}{2}$, $\angle DOC=75°$. One can also use slopes to find $\angle DOC$. If there is still error in your calculation you should show your calculation of angle with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Your method sounds right, but I cannot tell you where you went wrong, because you did not show the result of each step.

Anyway, here's another method:

$AO=AD$ because they are both radii of the circle.
$AO=DO$ because they meet at the perpendicular bisector of $AD$.
$\therefore \triangle{AOD}$ is equilateral.
$\therefore \angle{ADO}=60^{\text{o}}$.
$\therefore \angle{CDO}=30^{\text{o}}$.
$DC=DO$ because they both equal $AD$.
$\therefore \triangle{DOC}$ is isosceles.
$\therefore \angle{DOC}=75^{\text{o}}$.